# Dissolve multiple polygons and keeping attributes

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I am new to QGIS. I have vector data with many greenspaces in a city. I want to merge neigbouring polygons. I did this using dissolve which works fine (see below, brown before dissolve, green after).

However, after using dissolve I end up with only one item in the attribute table. This is problematic because after dissolve and delete holes, I would like to remove the remaining smaller polygons by using the area column in the table.

Is there a way to keep the attribute table. Or create a new list with all the new polygons, I do not need to keep the attributes from the original table.

[image: After dissolve]

[image: attribute table after dissolve]

Comment: You can use the tool *Multipart to singleparts* on your dissolved layer to separate the polygons.

Comment: You can also select a field to dissolve by (e.g. name of park if all the adjacent polygons have the same name attribute, or same region name, etc) and you will have separate features with merged geometries categorised by that field. (e.g. one merged polygon for each park, or region, etc.)

Comment: In version 3.27 there's a [Keep disjoint features separate](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) parameter in the dissolve algorithm.